# I can't access my environment variable in file.js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, environment-variables

I define REACT_APP_ADMIN_URL in my .envrc file, i want to use it as a component link, but i get only empty or undefined

This my environment variable, in file .envrc

```
REACT_APP_ADMIN_URL="http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin"
```

in file consts.js i make

```
export const ADMIN_URL = process.env.REACT_APP_ADMIN_URL;
```

and in my page i make this

```
import { ADMIN_URL } from './Consts';

<Menu href={ADMIN_URL}>Admin</Menu>
```

but doesnt work, in my inspector console i get this

```
<a href="#" role="menuitem" tabindex="-1">Admin</a>
```

Comment: Not sure if that is the problem, but I've never seen .envrc files in a Node project before, only .env ones. Maybe try to change the name ?

Comment: Thanks but doesn`t work

Answer (score 1):

I think that you have to load the environment variables from the .env file on runtime, you can use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package to do so.

1. Install the package using `npm i dotenv`
2. Create a .env file in the root directory of your project. Add environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of NAME=VALUE.
3. Put this line `require('dotenv').config()` before using the environment variables on your code.
4. process.env now has the keys and values you defined in your .env file

Comment: sorry but how can i do that?

Comment: Updated the answer. please check it out.

Comment: ok, but i get                                                                                                   
ERROR in ./node_modules/dotenv/lib/main.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/r13/dev/projects/educat-flask/node_modules/dotenv/lib'

Comment: Are you using it in the client side or the server side? what environment is it NodeJS?

Comment: client side,  Node.js v12.11.1.

Comment: If you're going to use in the client-side then you need to use webpacks, refer to this: https://github.com/react-boilerplate/react-boilerplate/issues/1250, However, I wouldn't recommend that. It doesn't make since to use env variables in client side.